# JSON wrong encoding in android app

Tags: java, android, json, eclipse

In my android app I am using JSON to get data from a wordpress website. It works good except the fact that just in titles of articles there are some weird characters. I don't know why if encoding is good with other text content why is it that if title has some non-standard character like "&" it gives some question marks etc. Here is my JSON parsing code I would be thankful if someone could take a look and answer me what is wrong with encoding here ?

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if (null != feedList) {
            updateList();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        String url = params[0];

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = getJSONFromUrl(url);

        // parsing json data
        parseJson(json);
        return null;
    }
}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
    InputStream is = null;
    JSONObject jObj = null;
    String json = null;

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
         URL httpurl = new URL(url);
         HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) httpurl.openConnection();
         is = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());


        // BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        // is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "utf-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}

public void parseJson(JSONObject json) {
    try {

        // parsing json object
        if (json.getString("status").equalsIgnoreCase("ok")) {
            JSONArray posts = json.getJSONArray("posts");

            feedList = new ArrayList<FeedItem>();

            for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject post = (JSONObject) posts.getJSONObject(i);
                FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
                item.setTitle(post.getString("title"));
                item.setDate(post.getString("date"));
                item.setId(post.getString("id"));
                item.setUrl(post.getString("url"));
                item.setContent(post.getString("content"));
                item.setCustomFields(post.getString("custom_fields"));

                JSONArray attachments = post.getJSONArray("attachments");

                if (null != attachments && attachments.length() > 0) {
                    JSONObject attachment = attachments.getJSONObject(0);
                    if (attachment != null)
                        item.setAttachmentUrl(attachment.getString("url"));
                }

                feedList.add(item);
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use GSON to save all the parsing thing? Check it out. It might "fix" your problem too: https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: Did you check the HTTP response to know on which encoding the JSON is being returned?

Comment: Can you explain a bit how to check that ?

Comment: I quit with solving this issue and just removed problematic values from the title of every post.